# Parse dynamic json element to the same field

Tags: json, typescript, jsonparser

I try to convert a json response to a list of persons.
This solution works but maybe there is a better solution to parse it. 
(I can't change the response structure, but i can change the person if necessary)

Json Response:

{
  "name1": {
    "address": "abc",
    "city": "xy"
  },
  "name2": {
    "address": "abcdef",
    "city": "xyzzzz"
  }
}

My Person:

```
class Person{
name:string;
city:string;
address:string;

constructor(name: string, city: string, address: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.city = city;
    this.address = address;
}
```

}

My example implementation:

```
const value = JSON.parse(data);
const arr:Person[] = [];
for (var key in value) {
    if (value.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        arr.push(new Person(key, value[key].city, value[key].address));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.parse is dangerous, you must do with try catch

```
let value
try { 
  value = JSON.parse(data);
} catch (err) {
  value = {};
}

const arr:Person[] = Object.keys(value)
.map(key => new Person(key, value[key].city, value[key].address));
```

Comment: yes, this was only an example code to show the problem/solution,... in the real application i have a try/catch around it ... but thanks anyway :))

Comment: see parse exapmle as well